# I can't find the critical points for this function. I showed my work :)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So, I have to find Critical Points of $y=\frac{1}{(x^3-x)}$
I know the derivative.

Derivative = $(3x^2-1)/(x^3-x)^2$

To find Critical Points I equal to $0$.

$x=1/\sqrt3$ and $x=-1/\sqrt3 $

But Critical points are the Max and Min value of your graph... and the graph is a little tricky... I don't know what to do... Because in my opinion, there are no critical points. It goes to infinity and -infinity.
Opinions? Help please!
[image]

Comment: No, the derivative is $\frac{-(3x^2-1)}{(x^3-x)^2}$. You missed the minus sign.

Comment: It is the same result though....

Comment: The derivative is not negative... Try to do it again just to double check :)

Comment: The derivative is negative... but you can multiply everything by -1 and is ok.

Comment: yes, the zeroes of the derivative remain the same. Critical point is by definition a point $x_0$ at which either $f'(x_0)=0$ or $f'(x_0)$ doesn't exist with $f(x_0)$ existing. So $3x^2-1=0$ gives all the critical points, which are $x_0=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. $x^3-x=0$ doesn't give any critical points because $f(x)$ is not defined when $x^3-x=0$.

Comment: x = 0 can't be a critical point... x = 0 is a vertical asymptote..

Comment: @user31415: Yes, I was about to add that it is a common mistake to think that critical points are only associated with a vanishing derivative. They also occur when the derivative doesn't exist. +1.

Comment: So, in this case, The Critical points are the vertical asymptotes?

Comment: @Julio: You are mistaken. Not just where $f'=0$, but also where $f'$ fails to exist. Both cases are among domain points, of course.

Comment: f' = 0 in 1/√3 and -1/√3

Comment: @user31415: Of course, a maximum or minimum can only occur at a point in the domain. Otherwise, how can it be an extreme value ("value" is, by definition, a value assumed by the function at a domain point). But I think I see your point--zeroes of the derivative's denominator don't produce critical points if they are also, say, zeroes of the original function's denominator. Good point.

Comment: I am a little confused now... So there are no critical points?

Comment: @Julio Again, a critical point is by definition a point $x_0$ in the domain at which either $f'(x_0)=0$ or $f'(x_0)$ doesn't exist. $\frac{-(3x^2-1)}{(x^3-x)^2}=0\iff x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\frac{-(3x^2-1)}{(x^3-x)^2}$ is always defined for $x$ in the domain $\text{D}=(-\infty;+\infty)\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$. So all the critical points are $x_0=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: And if I have to do a slope chart, would I use the intervals: x<-1/√3, x=-1/√3 and x>-1/√3? for the max value?

Comment: And for the min value I use x<1/√3, x=1/√3 and x>1/√3?

Comment: @Julio $f'(x)=\frac{-(3x^2-1)}{(x^3-x)^2}=\frac{-3(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})}{x^2(x-1)^2(x+1)^2}$ and so $f'(x)>0$ iff $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}),x\neq 0$ and $f'(x)<0$ iff $((x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})\text{ or }(x<-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})),x\not\in\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: You guys helped a lot, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The points you found are just local extrema. Regarding the + and - $\infty$, you can simply note that those are local maxima of the function.